# Keep two floated divs on the same line inside a smaller container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a layout that roughly looks like [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bdxs8x9r/1/). Now, the problem is:

I have this two wrappers inside my `container`, one is for the sidebar and the other (`wrapper-inner-container`) is for the page content itself, both are floated to the left and the `wrapper-sidebar` has a mechanism to hide and show.

The thing is, when the `wrapper-sidebar` is visible, the `wrapper-inner-container`, which has a `width` of `100vw`, should stay floated to the left , on the same line as the `wrapper-sidebar` and the parent `container` should remain with the same `width` of `100vw` and simply hide the horizontal overflow. But, as you can see in the JSFiddle, what happens is that since both wrappers in the same line exceed the width of the container, the `wrapper-inner-container` jumps to the next line, when it was supposed to stay on the same line as the `wrapper-sidebar` and remain with a `width` of `100vw`. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your purpose is for `wrapper-inner-container` to take up the remaining space with `wrapper-sidebar` visible or not. Then you can do this be leaving out the width of `wrapper-inner-container` and removing `float: left`. It will then automatically size to 100% available space because it's a block element.

https://jsfiddle.net/bdxs8x9r/4/ (updated)

Also here's an example of how you can achieve it a bit more consistently with `flex-box`:

The trick here is that `wrapper-sidebar` has a fixed width and `wrapper-inner-container` flexes to it's remaining space in the container.

https://jsfiddle.net/bdxs8x9r/3/

Comment: Indeed, it turns out that using flex-box is much simpler, thanks

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you must be creating a parent container which contains the main container, which you'll set its overflow to hidden and its width to **100vw**

then set the main container width to **100vw plus the sidebar size**, so this way the sidebar will have the space to push the inner-container into

```
<style>
.overflow {
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
    width: 115vw;
}
.wrapper-sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 15vw;
}
.wrapper-inner-container {
    width: 100vw;
    float: left;
}
</style>

<script>
 // do your animation code here
</script>

<div class="overflow">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper-sidebar"></div>
        <div class="wrapper-inner-container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```